# Seperator in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to use seperator inside my join statement but it keep on doesn't work. I tried following some website and question to do but still doesn't work. Can someone guide me on where did I go wrong? Could it be because of the way I use it?

Here is the code:

```
$data = PersonalInfo::join('evaluations','evaluations.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id')
-> join('qualifications', 'personal_infos.id', '=', 'qualifications.user_id') 
-> join( 'language_proficiencies', 'personal_infos.id', '=', 'language_proficiencies.user_id')
-> join( 'families', 'personal_infos.id', '=', 'families.user_id')


    ->select( 
      'language_proficiencies.meta_value as Language',
      'qualifications.meta_value as Education',
      'families.meta_value as Immediate Family',
      'personal_infos.name as Name',
      'personal_infos.created_at as Date')
    ->whereDate('personal_infos.created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d')) 
    ->where('evaluations.Evaluation_Status', '=', 'Yes') 
    ->where('language_proficiencies.meta_key' , '=', 'Language_Name') 
    ->where('qualifications.meta_key' , '=', 'qualification_list') 
    ->where('families.meta_key' , '=', 'relationshiplist') 
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

I did something like this but it doesn't work

```
   // DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(language_proficiencies.meta_value SEPARATOR ', ')) as 'Language'",
     // DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(qualifications.meta_value SEPARATOR ', ')) as 'Education'",
       // DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(families.meta_value SEPARATOR ', ')) as 'Immediate Family'",

     // GROUP_CONCAT(language_proficiencies.meta_value SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Language',
      //GROUP_CONCAT(qualifications.meta_value SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Education',
      //GROUP_CONCAT(families.meta_value  SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Immediate Family',
```

EDIT:
Just want to do separator on qualification, language_proficiencies and families, I removed some codes to prevent it from being too messy.

Comment: **I am trying to use seperator inside my join** what's a seperator?

Comment: I want to do something like an implode on my data and I saw something similar to it was the separator function. I tried following this website but doesn't work for me, so I was thinking if i did anything wrong here, http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/group-concat-with-separator-in-laravel-exampleexample.html

Comment: Or am I using the wrong function here?

Comment: why not do a simple implode?

Comment: I thought implode can only be done when saving data? Is it? I am trying to get data from database but because they are in different rows there is a lot of data being shown how do I use implode in this situation? Or can I do implode in select statement?

Comment: you implode using the php function `implode()`

Comment: I know the implode function but how do I do it in select statement inside? Because the only time I did was when I try save my data into database.

Comment: you don't do it in the select statement you do it in a loopp

Comment: Erm, ok maybe I update my question first and you see what am I having trouble with

Comment: @madalinivascu actually never mind M Khalid Junaid solve my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you should use `GROUP BY` clause because its an aggregate function, with grouping criteria your whole table will be considered as a single group and the values of all rows concatenated as comma separated list or a list with your defined separator

```
$data = PersonalInfo::join('evaluations','evaluations.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id')
    -> join('qualifications', 'personal_infos.id', '=', 'qualifications.user_id') 
    -> join( 'language_proficiencies', 'personal_infos.id', '=', 'language_proficiencies.user_id')
    -> join( 'families', 'personal_infos.id', '=', 'families.user_id')
    ->select( 
      DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(language_proficiencies.meta_value SEPARATOR ', ')) as Language"),
      DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(qualifications.meta_value SEPARATOR ', ')) as Education"),
      DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(families.meta_value SEPARATOR ', ')) as ImmediateFamily"),
      'personal_infos.name as Name',
      'personal_infos.created_at as Date')
    ->whereDate('personal_infos.created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d')) 
    ->where('evaluations.Evaluation_Status', '=', 'Yes') 
    ->where('language_proficiencies.meta_key' , '=', 'Language_Name') 
    ->where('qualifications.meta_key' , '=', 'qualification_list') 
    ->where('families.meta_key' , '=', 'relationshiplist') 
    ->groupBy('personal_infos.name')
    ->groupBy('personal_infos.created_at')
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

> Also note there is a limitation on character limit using `GROUP_CONCAT` as per docs *The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet*

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it what I needed, just some question when I forgot to put the GroupBy function it didn't really affect the result so what is the use of putting it in?

Comment: @Dkna it still give you result but as a single row not for each personal_infos that is why i added the group by by your question which seems like for each record of personal_infos there are multiple relations which you need as a list in individual rows

Comment: Ohh I see, sorry about that, it was my first time hearing the groupBy function. And also thank you so much for helping me :)